# Android Studio java - RecyclerView Adapter Returning Empty Song List in onSave

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

The app is creating a "set list" of songs as the user swipes the song from a list of 'candidate' songs into the final 'set list of songs'.  I can see that this "set list" is created and within my onSave (`btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`) method (see screenshote below).  I wish to view all my parameters prior to saving into the database.  It is at this juncture - viewing my data prior to starting the save into the database - where I cannot access the contents of this list - cannot access the songs contained within this list.

The list is from my `RecyclerView` `setListRecclerView` as defined here (at class level):

```
private RecyclerView setListRecyclerView;
private SetListAdapter setListAdapter;
```

and within `onCreate`:

```
        // Set the adapter for setListRecyclerView
        setListAdapter = new SetListAdapter(setListSongs);
        setListRecyclerView.setAdapter(setListAdapter);
```

While in debug mode I can see the data from my `RecyclerView` `setListAdapter` by expanding into `setListSongs` as per the screenshot below:

[image]

I am trying to access the list via Log.d here:

```
                for (Songs song : setListAdapter.getFilteredSongs()) {
                    Log.d("SstList", "(CandidateSongsActivity) line #763 - SongId: " + song.getSongId() + ", SongName: " + song.getSongName());
                }
```

However the size is '0':

```
Log.d("SstList", "(CandidateSongsActivity) line #762 - Number of songs in the list: " + setListAdapter.getFilteredSongs().size());
```

So first I wish to view the contents within the list via `Log.d` to ensure all are included.  After this I will load into my database.  However first any suggestions on how to view my list and load a comma delimited list of "songId" values into my database table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the `getFilteredSongs()` method in the `SetListAdapter` class.

It was returning an empty array - once adjusting the `return` variable with the correct list from `Songs` model class, the code worked with the proper list being returned - here is the method call:

```
Songs song : setListAdapter.getFilteredSongs()
```

The return from this method in the `SetListAdapter` class was the error, it returned an empty list:

```
    public List<Songs> getFilteredSongs() {
        if (setListSongs == null) {
            // Initialize filteredSongs if it's null
            filteredSongs = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return setListSongs;  // setListSongs is the correct return array
    }
```

One last observation is that in the screenshot of my debug screen I was able to navigate into the `setListAdapter` object and within this view could see the various other lists that are being utilized within the class.  Thus that is the reason I was 'seeing' the completed array of songs `setListSongs` however the method was returning a different list of songs...